# How authentic is the haadith where Rasul (PBUH) said ameen three times?

Tags: authenticity

[image]

I searched for this haadith on the internet but couldn't find anything useful to prove the authenticity of this narration.

Comment: Your question already quotes that the hadith is from Sahih Ibn Hibban, see [here](https://al-maktaba.org/book/1729/1362)

Comment: Proof of authenticity is a complex research. Usually, we would trust the research done by Al-Albani. Sahih means "very likely to be authentic"; it's not 100% but close-to.

Comment: @Jeschu why would you trust the qualification given by al-Albani? There are many hadith scholars. The hadith also appears in other sources as mentioned in the link shared by UmH.

Answer (score 0):

As a response to the legitimate question by Medi1Saif above, I put a try of a translation of the [original](https://al-maktaba.org/book/1729/1362) cited by UmH above:

> Ibn Alqama bin Waqas al-Laithi al-Madani: Al-Hafiz said in
> “Al-Taqreeb”: He is honest and (but?) has visions (?), and the rest of
> his men are trustworthy. Abu Muammar is Ismail bin Ibrahim bin Muammar
> Al-Hudhali.
>
> Al-Bukhari included it in Al-Adab Al-Mufrad No. (646) through Muhammad
> bin Abdullah, and Ismail Al-Qadi (18) through Abu Thabit, both on the
> authority of Ibn Abi Hazim, on the authority of Katheer, on the
> authority of Al-Walid Bin Rabah, on the authority of Abu Hurairah.
>
> It was included by Al-Bazzar (3169), and it was authenticated by Ibn
> Khuzaymah (1888) through Suleiman bin Bilal, on the authority of
> Katheer bin Zaid, with the aforementioned chain of transmission. And
> it came after him from Al-Maqbari, on the authority of Abu Hurairah.
>
> And in the chapter on the authority of Ka`b bin Ajrah, and on the
> authority of Anas bin Malik, according to Ismail Al-Qadi No. (15) and
> (19), and on the authority of Jabir bin Abdullah according to
> Al-Bukhari in “Al-Adab Al-Mufrad” (644), and on the authority of Ammar
> bin Yasser, Abdullah bin Masoud, and Jaber Bin Samra, and Abdullah

Abu Hibban, like Al-Bukhari and Muslim, tried to compile a Hadith collection that only consists of ahadith that he considered Sahih.

The quotation above is extracted from Shuaib Al Arnaout - as far as I know a  *secondary* evaluation in Hadith science, meaning that it already refers to prior research (which is usual and cannot be avoided). To make a complete evaluation, it is compulsory to know all sources (even if lost) as well as the «Book of Men». Extent information is compiled in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadith_studies#Criteria_to_be_a_%E1%B9%A3a%E1%B8%A5%C4%AB%E1%B8%A5_hadith).

For a valid evaluation of a Hadith, you really need to study in depth.
Answers on this site will always be on the base of evaluation of people who have studied in depth.

Muhammad Nasiruddin al-Albani (professor of Hadith science at the Islamic University of Madinah in the past century and member of the Wahabite movement) estimated this Hadith Sahih. Unfortunately, I did not find any public access to his works. They are often referenced on Sunnah.com.